# Why are shoes curved upwards?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, stress-strain

Why are shoes curved upwards?

I guess that the toes of the feet are stressed in tension but for what that upward curvature?

[image]

Comment: They simply follow the profile of your feet

Comment: And how about bananas?

Comment: @my2cts because it grows toward the sun

Comment: @Veronika This could also explain the shoes.

Comment: @my2cts You can write something better than this i am sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier to walk when there’s a curve. Otherwise the sole has to bend every time a step is taken. This will damage it over time.

Answer (score -2):

so that you don't trip on minuscule objects

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/292009)

Comment: @Semoi what a strange comment, I precisely answered the question without critique or request for clarification